# What are some good research topics for a high school student?

Tags: energy, reference-request, fuel, green-chemistry, teaching-lab

I absolutely love chemistry and I really want to take part in science fairs. I am also taking an AP chemistry class. Cleaner fuel and energy sources and air pollution (especially due to smog and vehicle exhaust) interest me. My initial idea was to make solar panels work along the lines of Chlorophyll, but that is a bit too advanced for my level. Where could I get inspiration for some science fair ideas or chemistry research topics (high school level)?

Comment: I would recommend asking professors at local colleges and universities. A lot of ISEF qualifiers and winners work with university professors on their research. Find topics that are interesting already being pursued, then reach out to them with your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green chemistry is a highly advanced topic. It ain't for the weak of heart, so it is probably not for below university level.

I personally favor pyrotechnics as relatively safe **iff every bit of safety rules is strictly followed** and stunningly spectacular topic that is pretty easy and cheap to do by own hands (most materials are inexpensive as well as most tools). However, it is **extremely** time-consuming and has questionable legal status in some countries (and for a good reason: safety may be easily compromised and potential for disaster is high).

Another interesting topic is fluorescence. Many compounds shine under UV light, and there are families of such compounds that are not exhaustively studied and yet are relatively easy to make. However, a deep study is required, but it is probably advanced school level.

With access to advanced materials/tools/labs more topics become available, but a full list of such tools is required to recommend anything.